# TopAppBar @composable invocations can only happen from the context of an @composable function

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was trying to add `TopAppBar`. When I tried to add the following code, I got

> @composable invocations can only happen from the context of an @composable function** error.

```
@Composable
fun appTopBar(name: String) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed))
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = name) },
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
            ) {
                
            }
        }, content = {

        })
}
```

But when I tried to delete the last `{}` of `TopAppBar`, the error was resolved. Like the following code.

```
@Composable
fun appTopBar(name: String) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed))
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = name) },
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
            )
        }, content = {

        })
}
```

My question is what is the difference between `TopAppBar(){}` and `TopAppBar()`. `{}` is generated automatically by the Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin trailing lambda can only be used with the last lambda argument.

When you're specifying it for `TopAppBar`, the only possible variant doesn't have `title` argument:

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: Dp = AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = AppBarDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) ...
```

On the other hand, `TopAppBar` which accepts `title` doesn't have a last lambda argument:

```
fun TopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: Dp = AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation
) ...
```

It was generated by AS, because of a bug. I've [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209060418) it.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is a parameter of your `TopAppBar`and its neccessary to pass!

when you deleted it you got that error.

for more information read this article:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions